# django_filters - Filters are not responsive (function based view)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-filter

Trying to implement a filter `django_filters` to an existing function based view.

The filter is rendering as it should, but nothing is happening.

There is a few question on the topic, so I am going to answer some potential questions:

1. I used `$ pip install django-filter`
2. I installed in my virtual environment
3. Filter.py is installed in the same app as the views

Something to mention in my filters.py, `import django_filters` is underlined in red ("Import "django_filters" could not be resolved"). I cant find why, but this could be a strong contender in the root cause of the problem.

**Settings file**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "crispy_forms",
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    
    'django_filters',
```

**models**

```
class Catalogue(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product', blank=True)
    product_title = models.TextField('Product Title', blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table='Catalogue'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_title)
```

**filters**

```
import django_filters

from .models import *

class CatalogueFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Catalogue
        fields = ['product_title']
```

**views**

```
from .filters import CatalogueFilter
def show_venue(request, venue_id):       

    if request.method == "POST" and 'btnreview_form' in request.POST:
        form = CatalogueReviewForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.product_id = venue_id # links to product ID in Catalogue Model and return product name
            data.venue_id = request.POST.get('venue_id') # prints venue ID in form
            data.user_id = request.user.id
            data.save()
            ven_id = request.POST.get('venue_id')
            print(data)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(ven_id)
    else:
        venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=venue_id)
        menu = Catalogue.objects.filter(venue=venue_id)
        categories = Catalogue.objects.filter(venue=venue_id).order_by('category_order')
        myFilter = CatalogueFilter(request.GET, Catalogue.objects.filter(venue=venue_id).order_by('category_order'))
```

**template** (I added a bit more than the basic code, as I am thinking the use of the table could be the problem)

```
    {% if not menu.all %}
    No menu available.
    
    {% else %}

    <form method="get">
        {{myFilter.form}}
    <button class ="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> 
    </form>
    </br>

        {% regroup categories by category_menu as category_menu_list %}
        {% for category_menu in category_menu_list %}
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    {{category_menu.grouper}}
                </th>
            </tr>
            {% for catalogue in category_menu.list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{catalogue.product_title}}
                </br>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-4">
                        <a class="button3 btn-block mybtn tx-tfm" href="{% url 'show-product-from-venue' catalogue.id %}?next={{ request.path|urlencode}}">Review</a>
                    </div>
                </td> 
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {%endfor%}
        </table>
        {%endfor%}
        {%endif%}
```

requirements

```
django-filter==22.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `qs` with filter like this

```
else:
    venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=venue_id)
    menu = Catalogue.objects.filter(venue=venue_id)
    categories = Catalogue.objects.filter(venue=venue_id).order_by('category_order')
    myFilter = CatalogueFilter(request.GET, ,queryset=categories)
    categories = myFilter.qs
```